# Calling WordPress Shortcodes from Asp.net MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress, asp.net-mvc-4

I have A Web-application Running on ASP.Net MVC 4 and Another one Running PHP using 
CMS WordPress .

I have A slider Plugin in The Wordpress Running As a ShortCode ,All I am I Asking Is If There is a way to Get Slider shortcode working in the MVC App without The Iframe. Or any Idea how to Move the slider plugin From WordPress To ASP.NET MVC4 Application, I am Only Need The Generated HTML and I Generated JavaScript.

I Am using WordPress 3.8 and the slider plugin is Revolution Slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run the slider on the MVC site - the answer is no.
If you want to get the *results* of the slider in your MVC site - the answer is iframe. Or you could fetch the page or load it via AJAX...

But honestly enough, there must be another way to go. Why don't just get the slider's Javascript code and mimic it on the MVC site?

A slider is not that hard to do, you just have to store (on db, file, wherever) which images you want to use and then load them on the page with the proper Javascript to manipulate them.

Sorry for the bad news, but my advice is "avoid going the road less travelled". ;)